OpenAI API error: "Unknown request URL: POST /v1/fine-tunes"
This is my code:
import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

openai.api_key = os.getenv('API_KEY')

def upload_file(file_path):
    try:
        response = openai.File.create(
            file=open(file_path, "rb"),
            purpose="fine-tune"
        )
        print("File uploaded successfully.")
        print(response)
        return response['id']
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error uploading file: {e}")
        return None

def create_fine_tune_task(file_id, model_name):
    try:

        response = openai.FineTune.create(
            training_file=file_id,
            model=model_name
        )
        print("Fine-tune job created successfully.")
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating fine-tune job: {e}")


file_path = "output/8ec61610f6a5652f31a664153c20803639747017.jsonl"
model_name = "gpt-3.5-turbo"

file_id = upload_file(file_path)
if file_id:

    create_fine_tune_task(file_id, model_name)

I'm getting the following error: Unknown request URL: POST /v1/fine-tunes

Problem
The method you're trying to use doesn't work with the OpenAI Python SDK >=v1.0.0 (if you're using Python) or OpenAI Node.js SDK >=v4.0.0 (if you're using Node.js). See the Python SDK migration guide or the Node.js SDK migration guide.
Python
The old SDK (i.e., v0.28.1) works with the following method:
client.FineTuningJob.create()

The new SDK (i.e., >=v1.0.0) works with the following method:
client.fine_tuning.jobs.create()

Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., client.Fine_Tuning.Jobs.create() will not work with the new SDK version).
Node.js
The old SDK (i.e., v3.3.0) works with the following method:
client.createFineTune()

The new SDK (i.e., >=v4.0.0) works with the following method:
client.fineTuning.jobs.create()

Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., client.FineTuning.Jobs.create() will not work with the new SDK version).
Solution
Python SDK v1.0.0 working example
import os
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(
  training_file="file-abc123", 
  model="gpt-4o-mini",
)

Node.js SDK v4.0.0 working example
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const client = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

async function main() {
  await client.fineTuning.jobs.create({
    training_file: "file-abc123",
    model: "gpt-4o-mini",
  });
}

main();

